# Clean up after external Java library

Tags: java, jar

I'm using some external, i.e. jar, library in my application which unfortunately does not properly clean up after itself, i.e. the second time I create an object from this library it does not work as expected. I suspect that it is because the library creates some threads which keep running, but I'm not sure.

Is there any way to force a complete clean up of the mess that external library creates?

Comment: I can provide some code, but it is VERY specific to the library I'm using, which happens to be microemu. Basically, I create an object from this library in a function, use it and return from this function. Next time I call this function (and create this object, etc) it does not work as expected

Comment: You might have to look at implementing some sort of nested classloader that you can instantiate and access the classes though that and destroy when done, perhaps OSGI.  
But this might add a lot of overhead for each call.  

Can you not get rid of the library or find something else to replace it?

Answer (score 1):

There might be reasons unrelated to threads. For example, static class initializers only run once, when the class is loaded for the first time. So something like this may be the cause:

```
public class StupidSingleton {
  private static StupidSingleton instance;

  public StupidSingleton() {
    if (instance == null) {
      instance = this;
    } else {
      instance.foo(); // the implementation is irrelevant in this context
    }
  }
}
```

Whatever it is, there are three basic solutions available:

1. Don't use the jar. Look for updates and alternatives.
2. Control the classloading with custom ClassLoader. It's a hard road.
3. Fix it. Even with no source you can use a debugger and decompile the classes. If you find the cause and can't get an official fix, you might still create proprietary_fixed.jar from the decompiled classes.